# Using grep find the exact words Inbox and Outbox in a file

Tags: bash, search, grep

So I'm kinda new to using Unix and all, and I'm having some trouble with some exercises. I need to find the words Inbox and Outbox and output them to the console from a file. However, within the file is a bunch of other strings; "the Inbox" "INBOX" "Outbox1" "InbOx" "Ibox" "I box"

I've been reading through the grep manual and searching online, but I still don't know how to isolate certain characters to get Inbox and Outbox to only output. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Research on [su], [unix.se] and [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a exact match it is

```
egrep -w 'Inbox|Outbox' your_input > your_output
```

or

```
grep -w 'Inbox\|Outbox' your_input > your_output
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just figured it out as I was reading! I wasn't sure if pipelines were allowed or not, but this works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: `|` is not pipeline, it is logic `or`. btw please mark the answer if it is right.